# Best way to schedule Tasks in JBoss 5.1.0 EAP?

Tags: timer, jboss, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, jobs

what is the best way to schedule recurring tasks in JBoss 5.1.0 EAP? the configuration should be persistent (i.e. stored in a database). we are looking for a solution that is clusterable.

EJB Timer does not seem to be the right tool for our problem as we don't have an initiating event that triggers the timer creation.

The shipped quartz resource adapter (JBoss 5.1.0. EAP) only seems to support in-memory-job-store tasks.

any help appreciated.

cheers
marcel

Comment: Quincy, thanks for your quick reply. we've tried to replace the "RAM job store" with the "jdbc job store" and jboss tried to serialize the "message endpoint factory" passed into the resource adapter. can you point us to a website detailing the configuration for the "jdbc job store". did you use the MBean approach or the resource adapter? cheers marcel, ps: i've accepted some question - thanks ;-)